# Google Sheets API - Import all named Ranges

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet with several named ranges.
I would like to import every single named range in the sheet and save them as individual objects named after the named range.
Furthermore, there are 4 similar blocks of data. Therefore the names of the ranges are structured like "block1_name1" "block1_name2" "block2_name1" "block2_name2" etc.

With the following code I can enter every range manually, but there are too many to enter them all manually:

```
const API_KEY = "###"; // Please set your API key.

const ID = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

const RANGE = ["Range1", "Range2"]; // Named ranges

const ranges = RANGE.map(e => `ranges=${encodeURIComponent(e)}`).join("&");

const response = await fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}/values:batchGet?key=${API_KEY}&${ranges}`);

const { valueRanges } = await response.json();

const obj = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => (o[RANGE[i]] = values, o), {});

console.log(obj);
```

How can I import every named range automatically?

How can I save them as a different objects for each datablock like block1.name1 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the named range list from Google Spreadsheet, and want to retrieve the values from the named ranges.
- And, you want to export the values as `{namedRange1: values1, namedRange2: values2,,,}`.
- You want to achieve this by directly requesting the endpoint of Sheets API with fetch API of Javascript.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const API_KEY = "###"; // Please set your API key.
const ID = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

// 1. Retrieve the named range list.
const base = `https:\/\/sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}`;
const res1 = await fetch(`${base}?key=${API_KEY}&fields=namedRanges(name)`);
const { namedRanges } = await res1.json();

// 2. Retrieve values from named ranges.
const ranges = namedRanges.map(({ name }) => `ranges=${encodeURIComponent(name)}`).join("&");
const res2 = await fetch(`${base}/values:batchGet?key=${API_KEY}&${ranges}`);
const { valueRanges } = await res2.json();

// 3. Create an output object.
const res = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => (o[namedRanges[i].name] = values, o), {});
console.log(res);

// For your 2nd question.
const res3 = valueRanges.reduce((o, { values }, i) => {
  const [k1, k2] = namedRanges[i].name.split("_");
  if (o[k1]) {
    o[k1][k2] = values;
  } else {
    o[k1] = { [k2]: values };
  }
  return o;
}, {});
console.log(res3);
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result can be seen at the console.

```json
{
  "block1_name2":[###values###],
  "block2_name2":[###values###],
  ,
  ,
  ,
}
```

#### Note:

- When you have a lot of named ranges, it is required to separate the request for retrieving the values, because of the limitation of the length of the URL. Please be careful about this.
- About your 2nd question, when you want to convert from `{"block1_name2":[###values###],,,}` to `{"block1": {"name2":[###values###]},,,}`, as a premise, I think that it is required to decide the format of the name of the named ranges. In this case, from your showing sample named ranges, it supposes that your format of the name of all named ranges is like `block#_name#`. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. If this was not useful, I apologize. By the way, in this case, when the named ranges are not included in the Spreadsheet, I think that an error occurs. In that case, please add `if (!namedRanges) return;` just after the line of `const { namedRanges } = await res1.json();`. By this, when the named ranges are not included in the Spreadsheet, the script is stopped without an error.

Comment: I just realized, the second part of the question is still open. The output now is "block1_name1":[value]. Could I also split the object into a set of sub objects, e.g. having an object "block1" with subobjects like "name1":[value]. This way I could more easily reference the individual data blocks like block1.name1

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. About `I just realized, the second part of the question is still open.`, unfortunately, I cannot find your 2nd question. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, generally, please include only one question in a question. And, first, how about resolving from your 1st question? If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The output now is "block1_name1":[value]. Could I also split the object into a set of sub objects, e.g. having an object "block1" with subobjects like "name1":[value].`. This is your 2nd question? Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Co0n You want to convert from `{"block1_name2":[###values###],,,}` to `{"block1": {"name2":[###values###]},,,}`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, as a premise, it is required to decide the format of the named ranges. In your actual situation, the format of the name of all named ranges is like `block#_name#`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I am sorry for explaining it badly. Let me retry: The output of your code is an object containing {"block1_name1":[###values###],"block1_name2":[###values###],
  "block2_name1":[###values###],  "block2_name2":[###values###], } . This means I can reference the values with "res.block2_name1". I would like to create a set of subobjects so  I can reference the values with "res.block2.name1" because I think I can more easily use the data this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249235/discussion-between-co0n-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I would like to ask the same question for your 2nd question. You want to convert from `{"block1_name2":[###values###],,,}` to `{"block1": {"name2":[###values###]},,,}`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, as a premise, it is required to decide the format of the named ranges. In your actual situation, the format of the name of all named ranges is like `block#_name#`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your 2nd question, please tell me.

Comment: Yes, this works as intended. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Co0n Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does this script use two read requests? Asking because of the 60 requests per minute usage limit (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits).

Comment: @Co0n About `does this script use two read requests? `, it's yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Method: spreadsheets.get` to list the ranges of a Google Spreadsheet. This is returned as an object.

```
{
      "namedRangeId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "test",
      "range": {
        "startRowIndex": 4,
        "endRowIndex": 10,
        "startColumnIndex": 0,
        "endColumnIndex": 3
      }
    },
```

A simple sample using the method, and limiting the field for name ranges only:

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({
      "spreadsheetId": "Google_Sheet_ID",
      "fields": "namedRanges"
    })
```

You can read more information about this method in the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

And there is a sample complete code on the same documentation. You can then use the name in `"name": "test",` to rename the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This doesnt seemt to import the contents of the cells, right?

Comment: No, it will only listen the range name and information to identify it. You can use a different method to get the data of the range. Using the `namedRangeId` or the name of the range.